# Заполнение контейнера std::map с учётом значений по умолчанию

Tags: c++, stl, map

Подскажите можно ли сделать следующую задачу "в одну строчку", т.е. с помощью stl сделать более компактной/быстрой/оптимальной

**есть** контейнер

```
std::map<int, int> objects;
```

в котором находятся какие-то ключи в каком-то диапазоне

**требуется** сформировать новый контейнер на основании предыдущего в диапазоне от `min` до `max`, так чтобы недостающие значения были нулевыми

сейчас делаю так (задача - некоторые данные перевести к гистограмному виду):

```
// сформировать гистограмму
const int histogramSize = histBins.second - histBins.first + 1;

int* histogramData = new int[histogramSize];

memset(histogramData, 0, sizeof(int) * histogramSize);

for (const auto &it : pointsData)
{
    if ((it.first >= histBins.first) && (it.first <= histBins.second))
        histogramData[it.first - histBins.first] = it.second;
}

// сформировать выходные данные
statistics_report_t output;

for (int binIndex = histBins.first; binIndex <= histBins.second; binIndex++)
    output.insert(statistics_report_pr(binIndex, histogramData[binIndex - histBins.first]));

delete[] histogramData;
```

Может можно какие-то куски кода переписать более оптимально (однокомандно)? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если обратиться к map через оператор [] к ключу, которого нет, то в map создастся узел с таким ключом и дефолтным значением (0 для int). Получается, что вообще не нужно никаких функций для расширения map, просто используйте такой синтаксис `int value = objects[key];` и вам вернётся 0, если нет значения по такому ключу. Если же всё же требуется, чтобы в map присутствовал весь диапазон ключей, то достаточно скопировать оригинальную map и сделать insert по данному диапазону. insert не меняет value по ключу, который уже есть в map.

```
std::map<int, int> objects = { {5,2},{6,3},{7,4} };
int min = 1;
int max = 10;

std::map<int, int> newMap = objects;
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    newMap.insert({ i, 0 });
}
```

Comment: Это ж медленно и насоздаёт с map't уйму ненужных записей...

Answer (score 5):

Тут наблюдается типичная проблема XY. Создавать и заполнять дополнительные контейнеры совсем необязательно, достаточно просто возвращать дефолтное значение, если элемент с требуемым ключом отсутствует в исходом контейнере.

Comment: VTT а можно поподробнее, немного не понял
это возможно реализовывать встроенными средствами stl?


а  разобрался - обращение по []

Comment: @Zhihar, плохая идея.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №...

```
void
complete(std::map<int, int>& m, int min, const int max)
{   while (m[min] || (min <= max)) ++min; }
```

Comment: Это ж медленно и насоздаёт с map't уйму ненужных записей...

Comment: никаких ненужных записей нет. Один из нас неправильно понел задачу

Comment: m[min] добавляет в map элемент со значением 0, что и само по себе не мгновенно, и размер карты увеличивает, из-за чего другие операции тоже будут делаться медленно. Если нужно что-то без дырок с последовательным доступом, логично брать вектор. Ну либо проверять в месте использования на существование ключей.

Comment: Кстати, а чего `m[min]` делает в условии цикла? Ты так всю карту до конца пролистаешь, если там ключи подряд. Его надо в теле ставить, а условие - просто `min <= max`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, такой вариант может быть.  Согласен и с  вашим вариантом. Спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (const auto &it : pointsData)
> {
>     if ((it.first >= histBins.first) && (it.first <= histBins.second))
> ```

Нет смысла пролистывать весь контейнер, когда нужен только фрагмент:

```
for (
  auto it = pointsData.lower_bound(histBins.first);
  *it != pointsData.end() && it.first <= histBins.second;
  ++it
) {
  ...
```